# integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow] - TinyCircuit

Tags: bluetooth

I have a tiny circuit Bluetooth shield and I was testing out the sample code that was provided by tinycircuit. However, when I tried uploading the sample code into the board, I kept having the following error. How can I solve this error?

[image]

this is the piece of code where there error seems to be happening.

```
#define  ADV_INTERVAL_MIN_MS  50
#define  ADV_INTERVAL_MAX_MS  100

void setConnectable(void)
{
  tBleStatus ret;

  const char local_name[] = {AD_TYPE_COMPLETE_LOCAL_NAME, 'B', 'l', 'u', 'e', 'N', 'R', 'G'};

  hci_le_set_scan_resp_data(0, NULL);
  PRINTF("General Discoverable Mode.\n");

  ret = aci_gap_set_discoverable(ADV_IND,
                                 (ADV_INTERVAL_MIN_MS * 1000) / 625, (ADV_INTERVAL_MAX_MS * 1000) / 625,
                                 STATIC_RANDOM_ADDR, NO_WHITE_LIST_USE,
                                 sizeof(local_name), local_name, 0, NULL, 0, 0);

  if (ret != BLE_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    PRINTF("%d\n", (uint8_t)ret);

}
```

Comment: What is ADV_INTERVAL_MIN_MS ?

Comment: `50 * 1000` > 32768. `100 * 1000` > 32768. It *shouldn't* matter, but best force it to a long by appending `L` to your defined numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the type of a number using suffixes such as `L`, `LL`,
`UL` and such. If you don't specify the type this way, all integers that
are small enough to fit in an `int` will be of type `int`. When you
write

```cpp
ADV_INTERVAL_MIN_MS * 1000
```

it gets expanded by the preprocessor to

```cpp
50 * 1000
```

Since both arguments are of type `int`, the compiler will use this type
to compute the result. However, the result is 50,000, and on 16-bit
systems the largest number that can fit in an `int` is 32,767, thus the
overflow.

As suggested by Majenko, the simple solution is to add the `L` suffix
(for `long`) to either operand. The compiler will then do the
arithmetics using the `long` data type.

Comment: Sorry uhm, what do you mean either operand ? I'm a little new on this.

Comment: The operands are 50 and 1000. Append the “L” suffix to either (or both) of them.